# How to take Oracle 11G EE DB backup using SQLDeveloper 4.1?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, database-backups

I want to take the Oracle DB backup, can you please tell me how to take backup using sqldeveloper client 4.1?

Comment: Why are you using SQL Developer to take a backup?  Are we talking about a physical backup?  Or a logical backup to supplement some other physical backup process that is already running?  Your physical backup would almost always be done in RMAN and configured either by text file scripts that you manually schedule or via Enterprise Manager (again scheduled).

Comment: yes, am using oracle sqldeveloper client connecting to remote databases, from this client I want to take DB backup instead of writing scripts. Don't we have the option to export database using this client?

Comment: So you want to take a logical backup?  Is there already an automated process in place to do regular physical backups?  If the databases are small enough, you could generate some logical backups using SQL Developer.  But if that should not be the primary means of backing up the database.   And it would be rather slow and tediously repetitive if you are working with many databases and generating these logical backups regularly particularly if the databases are of any size.